# awk with joined field

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I am trying to extract data from one file, based on another.
The substring from file1 serves as an index to find matches in file2.
All works when the string to be searched inf file2 is beetween spaces or isolated, but when is joined to other fields awk cannot find it. is there a way to have awk match any part of the strings in file2 ?

```
awk -vv1="$Var1" -vv2="$var2" '
    NR==FNR {
        if ($4==v1 && $5==v2) {
            s=substr($0,4,8)
        echo $s 
            a[s]++
        }
        next
    }
    !($1 in a) {
        print
    }' /tmp/file1 /tmp/file2
```

example that works:
file1:

```
1  554545352014-01-21      2014-01-21T16:18:01     FS  14001 1         1.10
1  554545362014-01-21      2014-01-21T16:18:08     FS  14002 1         5.50
```

file2:

```
55454535   11       17   102  850Sande Fiambre   1.000
55454536   11       17    17  238Pesc. Dourada   1.000
```

example that does not work:

file2:

```
 5545453501/21/20142       1716:18 1   1     116:18
 5545453601/21/20142       1716:18 1   1     216:18
```

the string to be searched, for instance : 55454535 finds a match in the working example, but it doesn't in the bottom one.

Comment: Given your comment to bdrx's answer I think you are going to need to turn your `in a` match into a loop over `a` and regex `~` match against each item yourself.

Comment: get rid of the spurious shell command `echo $s` from the middle of your awk script. awk is seeing it as the string concatenation of the empty variable `echo` and the field indexed by whatever number is contained in variable `s`, so if `s` is set to `55454535` then you're accessing the field `$55454535`.

Comment: @Ed Morton, and what do u suggest I use instead of the echo $s ?

Comment: Are you trying to print the value of s? Then `print s`.

Comment: No, I am printing the records in file2 that match the substring s in file1

Comment: Then just remove the `echo $s` statement as it's unrelated to anything in file2, it's in a block that's only executed when parsing file1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to replace this:

```
!($1 in a) {
    print
}
```

with this (or similar - your requirements are unclear):

```
{
    found = 0
    for (s in a) {
        if ($1 ~ "^"s) {
            found = 1
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        print
    }
}
```

Comment: That's it. It works perfectly. Instead of printing I am catching the result in to a variable for post processing, but it does work. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex comparison ~ instead of ==

ex. if ($4 ~ v1 && $5 ~ v2)

Prepend v1/v2 with ^ if you want to the word to only begin with string and $ if you want to word to only end with it

Comment: in that case the comparison is made there :
    !($1 in a)
How do I use a regex comparison there !?